# Prove or disprove compactness for a subset of $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $$A = \{ p : \text{$p$ is a polynomial of degree less than $d$ such that} \max_{x \in [0,1]} |p(x)| \leq 1 \},$$
where $d \in \mathbb{N}.$ I need to prove or disprove compactness of $A$.

I know that $\{ f \in C([0,1]) : \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq 1 \}$ is not compact. But I'm not sure how restricting to polynomials of degree less than $d$ changes anything.

Comment: I'm glad to see that I'm not the only one in 522 that finds these problems challenging! ;) I thought I would add that the professor gave us the following corollary of Arzela-Ascoli that I believe can be applied in this case. If every $f\in F \subset C(X)$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $F' = \{f' : f \in F\}$ is bounded, then $F$ is relatively compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : set $B = \{ p : \text{$p$ polynomial of degree less than $d$} \}$

then $B$ is a finite dimension subspace of $C[0,1]$ so it is closed.

And hence $A$ is bounded and closed subset of $B.$

And thanks to Heine Borel theorem !